# JPA/Hibernate: Generating transaction id specific to a transaction and setting into JPA parent/child entities

Tags: hibernate, transactions, jpa-2.0

I have two tables like:

```
User [ UserId, FirstName, LastName, AddressId (#FK), UITransactionId ] 
Address [ AddressId, city, state, UITransactionId]
```

UITransactionId is to capture the specific transaction changes. For example, I have a add page where I can fill user First Name, Last Name and address. And If I save the user below records will be added into table.

```
 User [ U1, Narendra, Verma , A1 , 1234 ] 
 Address [ A1, Pune, MH, 1234]
```

The UITransactionId '1234' can be treated as the transaction id and logged into both table as user information and address are saved as one transaction.

Now if I update user name and address:

```
 User [ U1, NarendraEdit, Verma , A1 , 1255] 
 Address [ A1, PuneEdit, MH, 1255]
```

This time '1255' Id will represent as changes are made in both table with single transaction.

Now If I change the only address and save the user information:

```
 User [ U1, Narendra, Verma , A1 , 1255 ] 
 Address [ A1, Pune, MHEdit, 1295]  //Only this table is updated
```

This time '1295' should go into address table only, becase we have not updated user information but only address.

Is ther any way where I can generate transaction id specific to a JPA transaction and set into JPA parent/child entities?

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class })
    public void saveUser(UserVO userVO) {
     // Setting transaction Id into User/Address Entity
     // Call dao layer to save/update entity
    }
```

There is One way that I can generate random number in services while making a transaction and set explicitly to each entity while saving/updating specific entity. But this approach will require setting UITransactionId at each places to each entity. Is there any proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the good solution for tracking transaction id. I don't need to track transaction id at application level. I am using, update/delete triggers for storing audit related information whenever my tables are updated. Oracle triggers those are executed in a single transaction, they also executed under same transaction. I can get transaction id using '**dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id**' in trigger itself and log this while logging other audit related information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my answer helps, but this looks a bit like JPA's optimistic lock version, except that by default each entity has it's own version that is increased. You problem would probably be solved if the JPA implementation could somehow be configured to use a transaction id as the optimistic lock version.